# How to process form in template when you aren't printing the entire form

Tags: 7, forms, theming

I have a form where I am only printing out certain parts of it because I want to style around them.

i.e.

```
<?php print drupal_render($variables['form']['field_city']); ?>
```

However, when I try to submit this partial form, it doesn't work.

This is my submit:

```
<?php print drupal_render($variables['form']['submit']); ?>
```

Defined in the form like this:

```
  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#value' => t('CREATE NEW ACCOUNT'),
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#attributes' => array(
      'class' => array('form-submit', 'go-to-cart', 'user-register-submit'),
    ),
  );
```

But because of missing form elements, the form doesn't appear to submit. How do I fix this?

I am trying:

```
<?php
print drupal_render($variables['form']['form_id']);
print drupal_render($variables['form']['form_token']);
print drupal_render_children($form)
?>
```

But the first two don't seem to do anything for processing (it returns to the form page with all of the values filled in) and the third reprints the form without any sort of styling.

How do I get the form printed the way I want?

Comment: What kind of styling are you looking for in between form elements? Can you achieve it by just using fieldsets? You can also use [`theme()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/theme/7) within your `hook_form` or `hook_form_alter` to theme collapsible fieldsets and the like. That being said it is usually better practice to build forms through the UI.

Comment: I absolutely agree. However I was given legacy code, asked to update it and the client doesn't have the budget to redo everything the completely correct way. I'm replacing a template with custom form inputs, so this is a step forward.

Comment: Been there. I just have to explicitly state that kind of thing here because you never know who may come across this post.